# why wordpress editor modyfiying the codes?

Tags: wordpress, editor

I am trying to put to wordpress page folowing code using the editor

```
<a href="#" class="switch" gumby-trigger="#modal1">Open Modal</a>
```

It erasing gumby-trigger and leave it as:

```
 <a href="#" class="switch">Open Modal</a>
```

I install couple plugins and even one html snippets plugin but still modifying the content. How can I prevent wp editor to modify the codes?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that the editor strips unsupported/unofficial HTML attributes, so you might have to manually reinject those if you're set on using the Gumby framework.

Comment: Thank you. how can I reinject them?

Comment: That I don't know, I'm not familiar with Wordpress or its editor. Is there a way to upload manually-edited files to your WP instance maybe?

Comment: I'd be pretty sure the [wp_kses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) function is being called and doing that. According to the "Overriding kses" section of [this page](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/), you should be able to allow new attributes (I'm assuming you can add code to your theme's `functions.php`).  Or you could change your user to be an admin - the same page says "admins have the “unfiltered_html” capability, and can put anything they like in".

Comment: You'll have to add this attribute as allowed when initializing tinyMCE. Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444677/wordpress-visual-editor-tinymce-how-to-preserve-custom-attributes).

Comment: Thank you all. It worked except the close button. the code is like this:`<a href="#" class="switch close" gumby-trigger="|#modal1">Close Modal</a>`